# Customize Word 2003 toolbar

Tags: microsoft-word, toolbar, microsoft-word-2003, microsoft-office-2003

I want to remove the default images in the Word 2003 toolbar. Is there a way to change them?

Answer (score 0):

Click on **View > Toolbars > Customize...**

Ignore the dialog that pops up.

Right-click on the toolbar button you want to change the image to and click on **Edit Button Image...**

Unfortunately, when testing out this process, I noticed that some of the images cannot be changed.  I'm not exactly sure what the difference is there, but maybe the image you want to change isn't one of those exceptions.

[image]